# How to run s:iterator for a fixed number of times in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, iterator

I have a iterator in my struts 2 code as follows:

```
<s:iterator var="each_part" value="#request.rule.parts" status="eachpart">
```

Now, 'rule' is a POJO which is set into request in Struts2 action class. And 'parts' is an Arraylist of POJOs.

Now at runtime, there are 7 POJOs stored in arraylist 'parts', so iterator runs for 7 times.

Inside iterator tag , I'm creating a html table. So 7 tables are shown on jsp.

Now my requirement is to show 20 maximum tables, out of which 7 will be filled at runtime and other will be empty. But in my case, since iterator runs only for 7 times, only 7 tables are shown on jsp page.

Is there any way that the iterator runs for 20 times and picks property for first 7 times from arraylist and for remaining 13 times, it displays blank tables?

I tried this

```
<s:iterator var="each_part" value="(20).{#request.rule.parts}" status="eachpart">
```

but it didn't worked.

Please assist me on this.

Comment: Why not to use another iterator for empty tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `begin` and `end` attributes of the [Iterator](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/iterator.html):

```xml
<s:iterator begin="0" end="19" status="ctr">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <s:if test="#request.rule.parts.size >= #ctr.count">
                <s:set var="each_part" value="#request.rule.parts[#ctr.index]" />
                <s:property value="#each_part.field1" />
                <s:property value="#each_part.field2" />
            </s:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</s:iterator>
```

I've used `<s:set/>` to emulate the `var` attribute from your Iterator.

Or use two iterators, or fill your arraylist action-side up to 20 with a placeholder empty object, etc...

Also not sure why using request when you can use a getter.

Comment: This almost worked. I just had to make a minute change. <s:if test="#request.rule.parts.size >= #ctr.count">.

Comment: Ha, my mistake, fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

For a single iteration we can use following loop.

```
<s:iterator var="element" value="" begin="0" end="0">
</s:iterator>
```